# Load Two Dimensional Array from LINQ Query?

Tags: vb.net

I’m using VB.Net and have the following LINQ Query…

```
Dim ACFTTail5 = (From tailcounts In db.TailCounts _
                 Where tailcounts.Model = "UH-60A" _
                 Group tailcounts By _
                 tailcounts.Tail, tailcounts.Model _
                 Into g = Group Order By Tail _
                 Select Tail, rdf = CStr(g.Sum(Function(p) _ p.TailCount))).ToArray
```

I’m trying to get a two dimensional array like below..

```
    ACFTTail5 (0)(0) “Tail-a”
    ACFTTail5 (0)(1) “RDF-a”
    ACFTTail5 (1)(0) “Tail-b”
    ACFTTail5 (1)(1) “RDF-b”
    ACFTTail5 (2)(0) “Tail-c”
    ACFTTail5 (2)(1) “RDF-c”
```

ETC..

I have tried…

```
    Dim ACFTTail5(,) As String

    ACFTTail5 = (From tailcounts In db.TailCounts _
                 Where tailcounts.Model = "UH-60A" _
                 Group tailcounts By _
                 tailcounts.Tail, tailcounts.Model _
                 Into g = Group Order By Tail _
                 Select Tail, rdf = CStr(g.Sum(Function(p) p.TailCount)))
```

But get the following error…

“Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_4`2[System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.String[,]'."

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated…

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're stuck with the 2-d array?

Answer (score 0):

If you could be less concerned with forcing it into a 2d array, you could just allow the compiler to assign the anonymous IQueryable type and use that for iteration:

```
Dim ACFTTail5 = (From tailcounts In db.TailCounts _
             Where tailcounts.Model = "UH-60A" _
             Group tailcounts By _
             tailcounts.Tail, tailcounts.Model _
             Into g = Group Order By Tail _
             Select Tail, rdf = CStr(g.Sum(Function(p) p.TailCount)))
```

You could then just use the `For each` iterator to cycle through whatever you needed.

**Edit:**
I haven't tested this little piece by any stretch, but you should be able to use a List

```
Dim ACFTTail5 as List(Of String())

ACFTTail5 = new List(Of String())(From tailcounts In db.TailCounts _
             Where tailcounts.Model = "UH-60A" _
             Group tailcounts By _
             tailcounts.Tail, tailcounts.Model _
             Into g = Group Order By Tail _
             Select new String() { Tail, rdf = CStr(g.Sum(Function(p) p.TailCount)) })

Dim ACFTTail5_2d_Array as String(,) = ACFTTail5.ToArray()
```

The key that I'm using here is to select it directly into a new class (in this case a string array), and keep it in a List specifically for string arrays. Then you should be able to send that to a string array of string arrays.

Comment: I'm trying to get it into an array because I need to be able to sort on either "Tail" or "RDF" values later on in the application.

Comment: @Bear - posted an update. It may not be perfect or working (treat it as psuedo-code), but the idea should be solid.

Comment: Joel, This part works.. Dim ACFTTail5 As List(Of String()) ACFTTail5 = New List(Of String())(From tailcounts In db.TailCounts _ Where tailcounts.Model...  ETC    this part works and give an array. But "Dim ACFTTail5_2d_Array As String(,) = ACFTTail5.ToArray" give an error of "Value of type '1-dimensional array of 1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to '2-dimensional array of String' because '1-dimensional array of String' is not derived from 'String'"